# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly in Fib

Tags: python

I have work with a Fibonacci-like sequence in Python. Then I have to sum all the digits of the resultant numbers, and then take the sum these.

This is my code:

```
def fibSum(n):
    for x in str(n):

        x, n = x, x+int(n)
        print(x)
    print("The sum is: " + n)


def fib(n):
    total = 0
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
        # print (a)
        if a % 2 == 0:
            total += a
            print("sum = " + str(total))
            return fibSum(total)
fib(10)
```

Line 5 presents a problem, and if I use `str` instead of `int`, it says:

> ```
> x,n = x,x+ int(n)
> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
> ```

Comment: `x,n = x,x+ int(n)` This line doesn't appear in your code anywhere..

Comment: @ChadS. its the 5th line.

Comment: OP, can you indent your code properly?

Comment: Why are you explicitly typing everything? The beauty of Python is you don't need to do this. That said, if you are adding numbers why are you using `str()` instead of `int()`.

Comment: @Joshua Cook Because it throws the error, the line under the comment is where I used to have that, and it did not work. So I used the string just to not throw an error. Using the String I get 4444 when I should be getting 8.

Comment: @EvanTheis can you be a little more clear about what your program is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Isn't this a simple case of an implicit conversion in the `print` statement?

Comment: @Chad S. It is supposed to get the sum, of the sum of fib. So Fib will return 44 and then I am supposed to add 4 + 4, which should then be printing out 8.

Comment: I think perhaps your main issue is that `sum` is a built-in function in python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: @JoshuaCook Thank you, changed that. But I am still getting the same error

Comment: What are you trying to pass to your `sum` function - `list`, `int`, `str`?

Comment: Per my answer, the problem isn't the `n`, it's the `x`.

Comment: @JoshuaCook What's being passed is the int, 44. Which should be added up to 8 in the first function. All i've done with Python is codecademy. So I really don't know much. I started this challenges to learn Python, but everyone is going to downvote a beginner. lmao. All I need to do is add the returned value from the 2nd function to the 1st and then I'm good... What Fib should be called with is 2015. But this is easier for me since it's much smaller at the moment.

Comment: Where are you getting 44?

Comment: Random aside: you don't want a `return` statement inside your `for` loop in the `fib` function: it will break you out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We worked through your problem together on collabedit and this is the result. The confusion was that the actual problem was:

1. Calculate fib to the 2015th even sequence
2. Add only even numbers
3. With the final sum, sum each individual number

Here is the code:

```
"""
A generator that yields fib numbers
"""
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

# Instantiate the generator
f = fibonacci()

# Some vars to hold stuff
counter = 0
the_sum = 0

# Use our generator and loop
for x in f:
    # Bonus points for printing
    print x

    # If it is an even number
    if x % 2 == 0:
        # Add it up
        the_sum += x

        # Increment counter so we don't go too far
        counter += 1

        # Are we there yet?
        if (counter == 2015): break

# You don't want the final fib you want the sum of each
# number in the final fib
the_answer = 0

# Split the fib number into individual numbers
for n in list(str(the_sum)):
    the_answer += int(n) # Add each number together

# Tada
print the_answer
```

Answer (score 1):

A string in Python is also an array. Find the length of your numeric strings and Iterate over them adding as you go.

I would recommend not using a secondary function on your first pass. If it's a requirement get it to work then refactor.

This may be helpful

```
foo = '12345'
n = len(foo)

total = 0
for i in range(n):
     total += int(foo[i])

print total
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print an int, you have to convert it to a string first. Try changing the `print` statement to:

```
print("The sum is: " + str(n))
```

Comment: Or `print("The sum is:", n)` without convert.

Comment: This isn't the issue. It's whenever i'm adding that the error is occuring, on line 5. I'm getting the error in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to `print` something you want a `str`, and if you want to add something you want an `int`, and that `+` works differently for those types:

```
a = 1 + 2  # a=3
b = "1" + "2" # b="12"
```

When you do this:

```
x,n = x,x+ int(n)
```

If the second `x` is a string you will try to add `int(n)` (which is an integer) to a string, and that doesn't work. Fixing it would yield this:

```
>>> for x in str("12"):
...     x, n = x, int(x)+int(n)  # Forcing both values into numbers
...     print(x)
... 
1
2
>>>
```

N.B. I don't know if the above is your intended result. The function seems to be trying to iterate over a string, so it will break that string into an array of characters. Then, for each of those you're doing some weird tuple math with casting. This is pretty confused. To wit:

```
>>> for x in str(12):
...     print(x)
... 
1
2

>>> for x in 12:
...     print(x)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I think you either don't want to use a for loop there, or you need your input to be iterable. You may be looking for:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> result = reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y), str(12), 0)
>>> result
3
```

Which would make your function:

```
def fibSum(n):
    s = reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y), str(n), 0)
    print("The sum is: " + n)
```

`reduce` (when using an addition function) is a way of accumulating a value as you iterate through it. This is equivalent to:

```
x = 0
for n in int_list:
    x = x + n
return x
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed both x and n to type ints, and it got rid of the error... but now it's equalling to me 52 and I don't see logically how it is coming out to that...

Comment: *That* is a different question and has to do with the confusing way you're setting up your code. To answer it you'd have to be much more explicit about what each function is trying to do, your expected inputs and outputs, and where the expected output differs from your actual output. I recommend a separate question.

Comment: The first function is my only issue. The purpose of the fibSum function is to iterate through the total from the second function, so 44 = 4 + 4 would equals 8. And this is what I should be getting.

Comment: :/ I don't think that's what Fibonacci does.

Comment: This isn't a normal Fibonacci. A normal one would multiply. But this is a school challenge, and this is how they want it done. Because I could literally copy code from the internet. I don't understand why the hell my code isn't working that why I posted here. But everyone is downvoting me and that's absolutely ridiculous, we all learn but I must be the only one. lmao.

Comment: To be fair, people are downvoting because the question and your code is very confusing. It appears your actual question isn't what the original question is, which a sure sign right there. If it is not Fibonacci, saying 'Fibonacci-like' sequence will go a long way to making sure people understand there are functional differences.

Comment: I doubt that the two people engaging with you are the downvoters. Anyway, stack is harsh.

Comment: If my code is confusing, why wouldn't somebody point out where it is confusing? Also the first function should be the only place where it is confusing, because I have an idea in my head but I don't know how to successfully do it. Should I do something like in the second function with a total set to 0 and add it there, because at the moment it's adding, but it's adding on top of the returned value from the second function.

Comment: On S.O. it's helpful if you carefully explain what each function should do: what input it should take, and what it should output. This helps clarify, as do examples. Also, remember to upvote and accept answers of any respondents who helped you! This will attract even more serious respondents.

Comment: I suggest you explain the problem better because i don't think your code is close. Given fib(10) what would you expect the output to be, fib(100)? Here is my best guess with type fixes but I always get 2 https://repl.it/BTcw

Comment: I'm now blocked from here anyways, so I just would like to get help and leave. I've asked three questions and it's never been a pleasant experience. I'm trying to get the first function so that it's like the first one, but with iterating through n but how in the world do I do this without add 8 to 52?